# When I import my cvs to python it shows me only a size 1

Tags: python, pandas

My code is:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import pandas as pd

dataset= pd.read_csv('libro1.csv')
```

Where in my excel I have 60 rows and 14 columns

but it shows me a Dataframe of size (59,1)

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example. Without seeing the excel file, it's pretty much impossible for anyone to help you. Can you add a sample of your csv, and perhaps an image of what the file looks like when it's open in excel?

Comment: What happens when you try using a spreadsheet program to open the CSV?

Answer (score 2):

Pandas parses the first row as a header, so that's correct to have 59 rows in your case. You can disable this using `header=None` parameter.

Regarding the columns. Your csv file probably has non-standard delimiter like `\t`. Pandas assumes comma by default. Open the file in a simple text editor , check your delimiter and set the `sep` parameter if it is not a comma.

Answer (score 0):

Is this truly a .csv file or an .excel / .xlsx file?
If not, you should open it with *read_excel* rather than *read_csv*.

Comment: Hello, if I create the excel type .xlsx but I have saved it as type .csv to be able to import but it shows me the size of the actual rows but the column only 1